# matrix in visual basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, matrix

so i have a task to create a square matrix then from that return the average of the rows and columns, having some problem though

```
Dim m, n, i, j As Integer
        Dim A(2, 2) As Integer
        Console.Write(vbLf & "Enter The Matrix Elements any two : ")
        For i = 0 To 2 - 1
            For j = 0 To 2 = 1
                A(i, j) = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())
            Next
        Next
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Matrix A : ")
        For i = 0 To 2 - 1
            For j = 0 To 2 - 1
                Console.Write(vbLf & "{0}", A(i, j))
            Next

            Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Next


        Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Transpose Matrix : ")

        For i = 0 To 2 - 1
            For j = 0 To 2 - 1
                Console.Write(vbLf & "{0}", A(j, i))

            Next

            Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Next
    End Sub
```

This is my code, i know its supposed to be a square matrix so how would i do that, when i also try inputing the values it does not let me go past the next one, does anyone have code for a square matrix that gets its values from a user, or someone can help me please

Comment: Is For j = 0 To 2 = 1 a typo?

Comment: How big do you want this matrix? In vb, the subscript is the index of the last item, so `Dim A(2,2) As Integer` is actually a 3x3 array.

Comment: Also, I see this: `For j = 0 To 2 = 1`, which might just be a typo moving code to Stack Overflow, but is certainly not what you intend with the second `=` sign.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn i gave this code to someone and they edited that in, i don't know why, basically this is what i want, if say its a 2x2 matix, user is requested to enter, the values for the 4 values in the array, then the array is displayed, the values being                         
(a, b)                                                                                                               (c, d) - from this i can do the averages and other things, but its supposed to be a 2d array so really confused, appreciate ur help aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it generic, use the [GetUpperBound()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=netframework-4.7.2) function to determine how many elements are in your array for each dimension (it should be the same, however, since you have a square matrix):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim size As Integer = 3
    Dim numberWidth As Integer = 2
    Dim format As String = "D" & numberWidth

    Dim A(size - 1, size - 1) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
            Console.Write(String.Format("Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row {0}, Col {1}]: ", i, j))
            A(i, j) = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())
        Next
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Matrix A :")
    For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
        Console.Write("| ")
        For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
            Console.Write("{0} ", A(i, j).ToString(format))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("|")
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Transpose Matrix :")
    For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
        Console.Write("| ")
        For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
            Console.Write("{0} ", A(j, i).ToString(format))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("|")
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row 0, Col 0]: 1
Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row 0, Col 1]: 2
Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row 0, Col 2]: 3
Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row 1, Col 0]: 4
Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row 1, Col 1]: 5
Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row 1, Col 2]: 6
Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row 2, Col 0]: 7
Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row 2, Col 1]: 8
Enter The Matrix Element at A[Row 2, Col 2]: 9
Matrix A :
| 01 02 03 |
| 04 05 06 |
| 07 08 09 |
Transpose Matrix :
| 01 04 07 |
| 02 05 08 |
| 03 06 09 |
```

Here's a quick example of how to compute the SUM of each ROW:

```
Dim Total as Integer
For row As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
    Total = 0 ' reset for each row/column
    For col As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
        Total = Total + A(row, col)            
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Row " & row & " total: " & Total)
    ' ... do something else with "Total" here; like compute an average ...
Next
```

The code for computing the total of columns will be very similar, just swap the positions of the `For row` and `For col` lines.

Comment: thats cool bro yeah learnt about upper and lower bound in my last post, thanks for explaining, however how would i use this to be able to calculate the rows and column sum,

Comment: You can use the same nested for loop structure already being demonstrated for the output, to compute the sum of each row.  You'd switch the order of the rows/cols for loops to get the column sums.  I'll post something in a bit, have to hit the road.

Comment: yes i would have to calculate the averages and wanted to try this, however one problem, when i tried to enter this code just to see if it works, it would not work just got a error

Comment: Well...help me out here.  I can't see your screen (no magical power!); what error(s) are you getting?

Comment: oh thought you did have magical powers, errors is unhandled exception system.invalidcastexception: conversion from string "row" to type 'double' is not valid

Comment: "row" should simply be an **Integer** type so it can iterate over the array elements.  If you declared it as "string", then change that to "Integer".  Not sure why it's trying to convert it to double, that triggers my spidey sense...would need to see your code to confirm.

Comment: I just copied your code to see if to run, its exactly the same

Comment: Gotcha...sorry; that one is my fault.  Been programming in C# too much lately and I used `+` instead of `&` for string concatenation.  I will update the code above.

Comment: np bro, how was the road last night, all good yeah? appreciate your help once done ill try the averages and problems i know who to go too

Comment: smashed it mate, did the averages today and the column count today, thanks for explaining also bro

Comment: sorry for bothering you again, but how would you go about doing this : reads in a matrix from a text file, the first line of the text file has the dimensions of the matrix, the next lines will contain the elements by rows separated by spaces

Comment: Ask a question about that specific problem, then post here when it's up.

Comment: could you help mee pls

Comment: I've got a demo app mostly done. I'll post it in a bit, currently playing a board game with the family.

Comment: np bro, take your time, good luck with the game, hope you win ;D